# Determine file path relative to DOCUMENT_ROOT

Tags: php, symlink

I have a symbolic link `/var/www/sitename/html/lib/` which points to `/var/www/sitename/application/lib/`, and `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is `/var/www/sitename/html/`.

Within `/var/www/sitename/application/lib/testing/relative.php`, I wish to find the path of this file relative to the document root (i.e. `/lib/testing/relative.php`).  Note that `relative.php` contains a class and is not called directly.

If `relative.php` is called from a file also located within the symbolic link such as https://sitename/lib/testing.php, I could find the path relative to the document root, however, I can't do so from https://sitename/testing.php

Without hardcoding the path of the symbolic link, is it possible to find the path of `/var/www/sitename/application/lib/testing/relative.php` relative to the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` if called from a file not in the symbolic link?

Below shows what I have tried.

/var/www/sitename/lib/testing/relative.php

```
<?php
class relative {
    public function __construct()
    {
        $__FILE__=__FILE__;
        $PHP_SELF=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        $DOCUMENT_ROOT=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
        $SCRIPT_FILENAME=$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];
        $SCRIPT_FILENAME_REAL=realpath($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);

        $replace1=str_replace($PHP_SELF,'',$SCRIPT_FILENAME_REAL);
        $replace2=str_replace($replace1,'',__FILE__);

        echo("__FILE__              => $__FILE__\n");
        echo("PHP_SELF              => $PHP_SELF\n");
        echo("DOCUMENT_ROOT         => $DOCUMENT_ROOT\n");
        echo("SCRIPT_FILENAME       => $SCRIPT_FILENAME\n");
        echo("SCRIPT_FILENAME_REAL  => $SCRIPT_FILENAME_REAL\n\n");
        echo('str_replace($PHP_SELF,"",$SCRIPT_FILENAME_REAL)'."\n");
        echo('$replace1             => '.$replace1."\n\n");
        echo('str_replace(str_replace($PHP_SELF,"",$SCRIPT_FILENAME_REAL),"",__FILE__)'."\n");
        echo('$replace2             => '.$replace2);

    }
}
?>
```

/var/www/sitename/lib/testing.php

```
<?php
require_once('testing/relative.php');
new relative();  
?>
```

OUTPUT

```
__FILE__              => /var/www/sitename/application/lib/testing/relative.php
PHP_SELF              => /lib/testing.php
DOCUMENT_ROOT         => /var/www/sitename/html
SCRIPT_FILENAME       => /var/www/sitename/html/lib/testing.php
SCRIPT_FILENAME_REAL  => /var/www/sitename/application/lib/testing.php

str_replace($PHP_SELF,"",$SCRIPT_FILENAME_REAL)
$replace1             => /var/www/sitename/application

str_replace(str_replace($PHP_SELF,"",$SCRIPT_FILENAME_REAL),"",__FILE__)
$replace2             => /lib/testing/relative.php
```

/var/www/sitename/testing.php

```
<?php
require_once('lib/testing/relative.php');
new relative();  
?>
```

OUTPUT

```
__FILE__              => /var/www/sitename/application/lib/testing/relative.php
PHP_SELF              => /testing.php
DOCUMENT_ROOT         => /var/www/sitename/html
SCRIPT_FILENAME       => /var/www/sitename/html/testing.php
SCRIPT_FILENAME_REAL  => /var/www/sitename/html/testing.php

str_replace($PHP_SELF,"",$SCRIPT_FILENAME_REAL)
$replace1             => /var/www/sitename/html

str_replace(str_replace($PHP_SELF,"",$SCRIPT_FILENAME_REAL),"",__FILE__)
$replace2             => /var/www/sitename/application/lib/testing/relative.php
```